# php code for urls shortner not working, page not redirecting

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am using this code to create a urlshortner, that if a user from US visit the link he will be redirected to some page and if a user from any other country visit the link he will be redirected to some other page. It is not giving me any errors but not working either.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con){
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($con, "shortenedurls"); //Replace with your MySQL DB Name

$de= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["decode"]);

$sql = 'select * from short_urls where shorturl="$de"';
$urlid = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT id FROM short_urls WHERE shorturl="$de"');

$result=mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM redirect WHERE urlid="$urlid" LIKE "%US%"') or die(mysqli_error($con));
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0 ) {
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM short_urls WHERE shorturl="$de"');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result1)) {
        $res=$row['urlinput'];
        header("location:".$res);
    }
} else {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result)) {
        $res=$row['urlinput1'];
        header("location:".$res);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Step through line by line, print out the important variables and query results, and see where it's not working the way you expect it.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM redirect WHERE urlid="$urlid" LIKE "%US%"` This does not work. You can not chain comparison operators.

Comment: See this statement here, `$urlid = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT id FROM ...` and it's immdiate after statement. `mysqli_query()` returns a `mysqli_result` object, on success, from the *SELECT* statement, so `$urlid` is such object and you're directly using that in the immediate query, which will not work. Plus the formation of SQL statement is wrong.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: there is some problem in the " $urlid = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT id FROM short_urls WHERE shorturl="$de"'); "  it says object could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

```
"$de"
```

will not resolve correctly as it's also within single quotes; and they take precedence.  Swap single and double quotes and that issue is fixed.

For example

```
$urlid = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM short_urls 
                            WHERE shorturl='$de'");
```

Also this query is syntactically incorrect

```
$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM redirect 
                            WHERE urlid='$urlid' LIKE '%US%'")
```

Should be

```
$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM redirect 
                            WHERE urlid IKE '%US%'")
```

Comment: but what if i want it to satisfy both of the conditions, i mean urlid must be what $urlid is and it must have 'US' in the same row.

Comment: `$urlid` is not a string as Rajeep comments.